# scikit-learn Reference request: Feature importance for trees

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm trying to understand how the feature importance is calculated for regression trees (and their ensemble counterparts). I'm looking at the source code for the function `compute_feature_importances` in `/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx` and cannot quite follow the logic - and there is no reference.

Sorry this may be a very basic question, but I couldn't find a good literature reference for this, and I was hoping someone could either point me in the right direction, or quickly explain the code so I can keep digging.

Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with the decision tree in sklearn. A similar function is available in the R package randomForest.  In this case it is well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference is in the docs rather than the code:

```
`feature_importances_` : array of shape = [n_features]
    The feature importances. The higher, the more important the
    feature. The importance of a feature is computed as the (normalized)
    total reduction of the criterion brought by that feature.  It is also
    known as the Gini importance [4]_.

.. [4] L. Breiman, and A. Cutler, "Random Forests",
       http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm
```